# How to pop the Flutter View in my Project?

Tags: android, flutter

I have created a Flutter View in my Android project as such

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    View flutterView = Flutter.createView(
        MainActivity.this,
        getLifecycle(),
        "route1"
    );
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    // layout.leftMargin = 100;
    //layout.topMargin = 200;
    addContentView(flutterView, layout);
}
```

However, I am unable to pop/dismiss the View.
How can i pop this view in my dart code ?

Answer (score 1):

Edited: 
You can have the Flutter app dismiss itself by calling `Navigator.pop()` in the Dart code.

Comment: Its not working..it says "Undefined Name 'System Navigator' "

Comment: Try `Navigator.pop()`

Comment: That is leading to a black screen. Not returning to Android.